# Comparing two lists of different types with some arguments, select into another

Tags: c#, list, arguments, compare

I have two lists  of different types **a** and **b**, and I'd like to select data from list **b** to **c** that b.SureName= a.SName and b.LastName=b.LName and b.Date >= a.StartDate and b.Date <= a.EndDate.

Is this possible with lists? I think **c** list type needs to be same as **b**?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Please tag the programming language that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
public List<C> GetProperty(List<A> a, List<B> b)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<C>> ccc = 
              b.Select(bb => a.Where(aa => bb.SureName == aa.SName && 
                                                          bb.LastName == aa.LName && 
                                                          bb.Date >= aa.StartDate &&
                                                          bb.Date <= aa.EndDate)
    .Select(cc => new C() { FullName = cc.SName + " " + cc.LName }));

    return ccc.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
}

public class A
{
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string SureName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer but what is? cc => new CClass(){.CProperty = cc.SomeProperty} ? is this any property from list a or b or something else?

Comment: Having this c = b.Select(bb => a.Select(aa => bb.SureName == aa.SName and 
                                  bb.LastName == aa.LName and 
                                  bb.Date >= aa.StartDate and 
                                  bb.Date <= aa.EndDate) is as before before post, I have all from list b in c, also data that are out of a :(

Comment: Great, it's almost OK. Thank you so much, at the moment I have some duplicates - but perhaps they're comes from data. Let me check them out. Thank you once more :) Regards

Comment: Hello, what does mean "Mark this as answer"?

Comment: Click on the empty tick below this answers votes. It means that my answer is correct and solved your problem.

Comment: Mark this as answer then so that other users can also help themselves.